Ilumination Server Error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
[tolongin perbaiki laravel saya dan beri tahu cara nya
Internal Server Error
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from users where email = lidya23si@mahasiswa.pcr.ac.id)](https://i.sstatic.net/Jhs6042C.png)
Saya sudah mencoba mengganti nya tetapi tetap tidak bisa semoga ada yang dapat membantu saya dalam menyelesaikan permasalahan ini

SO is an English only site, so please ask your future questions in English. Please also do some srarching before you ask a qiestion as SO already has solutions to lots of problems. Lastly, please check if your question is about programming or sw development before asking. Access denied errors indicate issue with passwords, usernames, and permissions, none of which are programming problems.
